# parsing html data returned by ajax and get the value of a div

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am not an expert in jquery and ajax, (sorry if I bother you),  I have checked in internet and cannot find a simple response.

I'm interesting in the html data returned from ajax call that contains
...

```
<p id="id_comment"> 29 <p>
```

...

I would like to simply get the value 29 in a variable.

I did

```
$result = $(data).find("#id_comment");    ---  $result is an object
```

how can I simply get the value 29 in a variable?

Thanks

**--- EDIT**

```
array(
            'context'   => 'js:this',
                'data'      => array(),
                'type'      => 'POST',
                'success'   => 'js:function(data){

                alert(data);   --> return the entire html

                            $result = $(data).find("#id_comment").text();

                            alert ($result);  --> return nothing
```

Comment: What is the response html? please post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using jQuery simple selector:

`$result = $('#id_comment").text();`

Edit : In your case

`$result = $(data).find("#id_comment").text();`

Answer (score 0):

Try using result=$('#id_comment').text();

Comment: data is html data return from ajax call, so it is an object

Comment: my bad, it should be result=$(data).find('#id_comment').text();